# How to re-render a React Component Upon re-direct

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am creating a clone of SoundCloud, and when I delete a song from the song page, I want to re-direct to the song index component (the /discover page).

I am able to successfully re-direct there upon deletion, but the index page appears empty until I refresh, whereupon the songs are fetched. I've tried using a ComponentDidUpdate on the index page to fetchSongs again when the history.location is different, but haven't had success.

```
//Song Delete Component
handleDelete() {
    this.props.removeSong(this.props.songId)
    this.props.history.push("/discover");
}

//Song Index Component
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { 
    if (this.props.history.location.pathname !== 
        prevProps.location.pathname) {
        this.props.fetchSongs(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your redirect to a new component/route, that component gets re-mounted to the screen. You should use `componentDidMount()` instead;

### Discover Component:

```
componentDidMount() { 
     this.props.fetchSongs(); 
}
```

### Edit ---

Just learned that your second page is actually a modal and that you execute your `action-creator`and redirect in there. In that case, the `Discover` component may have not actually unmount from the screen, hence why `componentDidMount()` does not execute. But `componentDidUpdate(`) should still work, let's refactor it a bit

So in Discover Component, try something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(this.props.songsOrNameOfReducerKey !== prevProps.songsOrNameOfReducerKey){
        this.props.fetchSongs()
    }
}
```

`this.props.songsOrNameOfReducerKey` just refers to the redux-state that holds the updated list of songs - available as a prop in your component. We compare the updated list to our previous list, and if there is a difference, we execute your action-creator.
Make sure you connected `redux` to your component via `mapStateToProps()` to get a hold of this state-value. Replace `songsOrNameOfReducerKey` with the key that you defined.

When you delete the song from your list, it should give the Discover component, new props, thus triggering `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already have that code in place actually, but it still hasn't fetched nor displayed the songs.

Comment: Can you test to see if the component gets re-mounted upon redirecting? Maybe try console.log("test") inside componentDidMount() How does your dispatcher function look? @Ajay

Comment: I threw a debugger in my componentDidMount() function and noticed that the current delete implementation (pushing '/discover') did not hit that componentDidMount (nor the componentDidUpdate). Only upon refreshing did the debugger activate.

Comment: Makes sense. @Ajay is the Discover component actually still on the screen during the time of song deletion? I think its kind of weird to go on another page/route just to delete a song yes?

Comment: I'm following SoundClouds structure where you get to delete the song from the specific song page where a modal pops up. Then you delete the song and it should bring you back to the discover page which has a bunch of songs (the index page essentially)

Comment: @Ajay darn I just created a SoundCloud account to try this out. But don't think I'm seeing the same workflow :(

Comment: @Ajay, just found something that might be useful to you. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but still having issues. The this.props.history.push is not rendering the discover component, and not hitting either the componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate functions. The delete modal is appearing in the song show component (separate from discover), and then upon delete, is redirecting to the /discover which holds the song index component. If you're interested in the code, here's the repo: https://github.com/Ajay-Vishwanath/SoundCloud2/tree/master/frontend/components/song

Comment: Definitely, I'll take a look at this.

Comment: I actually just came up with a workaround. i threw a location.reload() after my this.props.history.location.push('/discover') and that was able to reload the page. Seems a little sketch and not designed perfectly, but it gets the job done.